# Verification needed: Clearable Python Queue class

Tags: python, queue, verification

Since I'm not an expert for Python and multi-threaded programming I'd like to ask you if my implementation is correct.

My aim was to extend the Queue class so it can be cleared. And the removed items should be returned. That's all. My implementation is:

```
import Queue

class ClearableQueue(Queue.Queue):

    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, maxsize)

    def clear(self):
        self.mutex.acquire()

        copyOfRemovedEntries = list(self.queue)
        self.queue.clear()
        self.unfinished_tasks = 0
        self.all_tasks_done.notifyAll()
        self.not_full.notifyAll()

        self.mutex.release()

        return copyOfRemovedEntries
```

Is it correct?
Thank you.

Update: Unfortunately, this implementation is still insufficient since task_done could throw the ValueError exception after clear() is called.

More precisely: The queue is thought to be used in a multi-threaded environment. So assume one producer and one worker thread (but you can consider more threads as well). Normally, if a worker thread calls get() a task_done() should be called after the worker has done its work. If this happens this way then it could happen that the producer thread call clear() for some reason, right after the worker thread has called get() and before task_done() has been called. This works so far, however, if the worker thread would like to call task_done() then the exception will be thrown. This is because task_done() checks the number of unfinished tasks by checking unfinished_tasks of the Queue class.

It would be interesting if this issue could be handled solely by the ClearableQueue class so the clear() method can be called without worries. Or if there has to be something different that controlls the method calls somehow.

Actually, in my concrete case I don't use the join() method so I don't need to call task_done(). However, I'd like to make this feature complete. Could be useful for other people as well.

Comment: Just a side-note: unless `self.mutex` should be used from outside, it's suggested to name it `self._mutex`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: mutex is inherited from the Queue class.

Comment: Looks like a fairly neat solution to me. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Jon Cage: No, I don't know how to test this properly. Would be intersting to know how a good unit test would look like, since it requires multi-threaded testing.

Comment: That's a good question ...I'm not sure myself :-) I would start with Google for some ideas: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=multithreaded+unit+tests&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: `clear()` should return `None` or to be named as `get_enqueued()` or `get_all_current()`.

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian: You are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be suffering some sort of race condition, and if I understand it, the current situation is that you sometimes get:

```
T1: |----->|------------->|-------------->|
    | get  |    some_opp  | task_done     |
T2: |---------->|------>|---------------->|
    | other_opp | clear | yet_another_opp |
```

Where clear is performed within `get` and `task_done`. This causes a crash. As I understand it you need some way do do this:

```
T1: |----->|------------->|-------------->|
    | get  |    some_opp  | task_done     |
T2: |---------->|------------------------>|------>|
    | other_opp | wait_for_task_done      | clear |
```

If this is correct, you may need a second lock, set by get and released by task_done, which says 'this queue can't be cleared'. You might then need to have a version of get and task_done that does not do this for special cases where you **really know that you're doing**.

An alternative to this is to have a more atomic lock which allows you to do this:

```
T1: |----->|------------------->|-------------->|------------->|
    | get  |    some_opp        | task_done     | finish_clear |
T2: |---------->|-------------->|---------------->|
    | other_opp | partial_clear | yet_another_opp |
```

Where you say 'I'm not done with this task but you can clear the rest, then tells task_done that the task had an attempt at being cleared, so it should do something after. This is starting to get fairly complex though.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed analysis! I think what you have posted here is the correct approach. And I think it should be doable but requires some careful consideration. I prefer this approach since it would not reduce the usability of the Queue class as it is the case with the solution provided by Jon Cage (there the surpressing of the exception decreases detection of possible misuses or misbehaviours). I won't get into this any deeper since the other solution of Jon Cage is sufficient for me. But it would be still  interesting to see the perfect solution, though...

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [the source](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/Queue.py?view=markup), you'll see that the standard way to access the mutex wraps the mutating code in a try: finally block in case something goes wrong:

```
import Queue

class ClearableQueue(Queue.Queue):

    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, maxsize)

    def clear(self):
        self.mutex.acquire()

        copyOfRemovedEntries = None
        try:
            copyOfRemovedEntries = list(self.queue)
            self.queue.clear()
            self.unfinished_tasks = 0
            self.all_tasks_done.notifyAll()
            self.not_full.notifyAll()
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

        return copyOfRemovedEntries
```

**Edit 1**

If you're worried about a second thread chucking exceptions when you do `get()` then `task_done()` why not just wrap `task_done()` in a try-catch block? All that exception tells you is that you is that you've acnowledged too many items, but if your clear function already took care of them, where's the issue?

This would hide that exception if it bothers you, make the intention of the functions more obvious and remove the double list-assignment in my previous example:

```
class ClearableQueue(Queue.Queue):

    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, maxsize)

    def get_all(self)
        self.mutex.acquire()

        try:
            copyOfRemovedEntries = list(self.queue)
            self.queue.clear()
            self.unfinished_tasks = 0
            self.all_tasks_done.notifyAll()
            self.not_full.notifyAll()
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

        return copyOfRemovedEntries

    def clear(self):
        self.get_all()

    def task_done(self):
        try:
            Queue.Queue.task_done(self)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

**Edit 2**

How about this as an even more effective solution which doesn't hide anything:

```
class ClearableQueue(Queue.Queue):

    def __init__(self, maxsize):
        Queue.Queue.__init__(self, maxsize)
        self.tasks_cleared = 0

    def get_all(self)
        self.mutex.acquire()

        try:
            copyOfRemovedEntries = list(self.queue)
            self.queue.clear()
            self.unfinished_tasks = 0
            self.all_tasks_done.notifyAll()
            self.not_full.notifyAll()
            self.tasks_cleared += len(copyOfRemovedEntries)
        finally:
            self.mutex.release()

        return copyOfRemovedEntries

    def clear(self):
        self.get_all()

    def task_done(self):
        self.all_tasks_done.acquire()
        try:
            unfinished = self.unfinished_tasks + self.tasks_cleared - 1
            if unfinished <= 0:
                if unfinished < 0:
                    raise ValueError('task_done() called too many times')
                self.all_tasks_done.notify_all()
            self.unfinished_tasks = unfinished - self.tasks_cleared
            self.tasks_cleared = 0
        finally:
            self.all_tasks_done.release()
```

I think this should avoid the exception but still behave in the way the original class was expected.

Comment: If you return different types(i.e.sometimes a list, sometimes None) this is best documented in your docstring (otherwise you're just making it harder to use for others)

Comment: @BiggAl: I think it's better to always return a list, but not None. This is an improvement. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Jon Cage: Sounds quite reasonable. In conjunction with BiggAl's reply this could be the perfect solution, I think.

Comment: @BiggAl: it will never return `None`.  Immediately after assigning `None` to `copyOfRemovedEntries`, it assigns a list to it.  Even if `list` raises an exception, then the exception will propagate from the function, not `None`.  The `copyOfRemovedEntries = None` statement actually is not needed, although one might say it enhances readability (at a small performance cost).

Comment: As I have tested it now this solution is still not perfect. Reason: The regular workflow is that after a get() call task_done() should be called. Now, when clear() is called between the other method calls then task_done() will throw this exception: ValueError: task_done() called too many times. Hm... how to deal with this?

Comment: @dappawit : you're right - I never use try without an except in my own code, so I just assumed it was there when I read it.

Comment: @Robert is this supposed to happen in between, or is it caused by some race condition? If it's supposed to happen then your task_done() needs to change to handle this case, otherwise you could do with stopping it from being able to arise, or handle it some other way. For threaded or multiprocess apps I tend to use an event queue which gets looped through. In this case I would handle this error by entering task_done back in the queue after then next command, effectively deferring it until it is possible to run it without error. In this case however you need to clear up after any side-effects.

Comment: @BiggAl: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying (sorry for my English skills). I have updated the original post. Please have a look. Maybe you can create a new answer if you have a suggestion.

Comment: @Robert : I have done so - it's fairly complicated so I included some ascii art to help illustrate my point.

Comment: @Jon Cage: Thanks for the edit of your answer. I think I will use it that way. However, the exception handling in the overridden task_done() could be problematic since a potential misuse of the class and method could be overseen as the exception does not gets thrown. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Robert: I agree on the override, but from your previous comments it sounded like handling that issue was a concern :-)

Comment: Added another example which avoids masking the exception.